# Finding the basis of a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following information:

[image]

The question I want to answer is: Give a basis for V.

Now I know that in place of A I should put a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$. However, according to the solution I have that means that:

- $a - c = 0$
- $b - d = 0$
- $2a - 2c = 0$
- $2b - 2d = 0$

While I thought it should be:

- $a - b = 0$
- $2c - 2d = 0$

Am I missing some formula or making some other mistake? Could someone help me in the right direction / give me an example on how to do this? Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the question that you're trying to answer about $V$?

Comment: Oh my bad! I put the question in there now. The question is: give a basis of V.

Comment: Thanks for that. How did you get that first equation?  That is, where did $a - b = 0$ come from?

Comment: I multiplied the same rows with each other. So row 1 of the first matrix is 1, -1 * a, b = 1a - 1b = a - b and the 0 comes from the given formula that says all those have to be 0. But clearly that's very incorrect, I'm just not sure why haha.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to type in critical information instead of pasting an image. Images of text are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: Will do! Could you point me to a page that shows me how to make matrices etc in here? I couldn't find it on the formatting page unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not multiplying matrices correctly.  The correct procedure is to take the dot-product of the *rows* from the first with the *columns* from the second.

In particular:
$$
\pmatrix{1&-1\\2&-2} \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = 
\pmatrix{
1\cdot a + (-1) \cdot c & 1 \cdot b + (-1) \cdot d\\
2\cdot a + (-2) \cdot c & 2 \cdot b + (-2) \cdot d}
$$

Comment: Since you're trying to grasp the basics here, I think it might help for you to watch through [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&index=2&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) by 3blue1brown.  In particular, you'll find that chapters 3 and 4 (the third and 4th videos) give a nice answer to the question of why matrix-multiplication is done in this seemingly strange way.

Answer (score 2):

Your first result is correct and gives that the matrix $A$ has $a=c$ and $b=d$, so it has the form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\a&b\end{pmatrix}
$$
so  a basis for the space of these matrices is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \qquad \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$